# CodeIgniter multiple database query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter

I tried to run query on multiple database with following sql query:

```
// Collect clients db name
$dbs = array();
foreach($cafes as $cafe)
{
    $dbs[] = $cafe->db_name; // client_7
}

// Run multi database query
foreach($dbs as $db)
{
    $this->db->select("$db.orders.*,(select count($db.order_items.id) from $db.order_items where $db.order_items.siparis_id = orders.id) as urun_sayisi, (select sum($db.order_items.tutari) from $db.order_items where $db.order_items.siparis_id = orders.id) as price");
}

$this->db->get()->result();
```

In above example, i have cafe clients and each client have own db named ex: client_7. I am trying to do list all client orders. I got following error with above query:

> Unknown table 'client_7' in field list

How can list all rows on orders table from multiple database?

Answer (score 3):

Please mention database name ahead your table name..
for example

```
SELECT userid FROM db1.user; 
SELECT userid FROM db2.user;
```

Comment: Great! It works but i'll try again with complex query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$secound_db= $this->load->database('database_two', TRUE);
$query = $secound_db->get('person');
var_dump($query);
```

[Source](http://devzone.co.in/connecting-multiple-databases-in-codeigniter/)

Comment: It should be single query and list whole data on same named table on diffrent databases.